# Variable c might not have been initialized

Tags: java

I have this piece of code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Config c;// = null;
    try {
      c = new Config();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error while parsing/reading file: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }   
    final NetworkReporter np = new NetworkReporter(c.getValues().serverIP, c.getValues().serverPort, (short)(c.getValues().checkInterval * c.getValues().checksPerReport));
    IdleChecker idleChecker = new IdleChecker(c.getValues().checkInterval, c.getValues().checksPerReport, c.getValues().idleSensitivity, new IdleChecker.reportFunction() {
        public void report() {
            np.report();
        }   
    }); 
    idleChecker.start();
}
```

When I compile this code I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project FanstisTime: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/amitg/Programming/Projects/FantisTime/FantisTime/src/main/java/com/amitg/fantistimeclient/Client.java:[13,54] variable c might not have been initialized
```

I do understand what `variable c might not have been initialize` means, and in fact - it will always be initialized (because the program will exit if it can't be initialized). I must have this try catch there because `new Config()` throws some exceptions. I tried using `Config c = null;` there and it gave me this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project FanstisTime: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

Do you know what can I do to solve that?
Thank you!

Comment: Try adding a `return` after the `System.exit`.

Comment: You could move everything into the try. Everything from `final NetworkReporter np` down to `idleChecker.start();` could go right after `c = new Config();` and it would remove the compile time error. You might accidentally catch some errors you didn't know about with this though, I'm not familiar with these classes or how they work.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Mmm... No, I actually should have mentioned that I tried that, I forgot to write that. it still gives me `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project FanstisTime: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Well, you should have stack traces printed properly, because the NPE is probably from somewhere else.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn It compiles now, but It's now always throwing a blank NullPointerException.

Comment: Besides, you should avoid catching the `Exception` class – it's too generic. Try to use a more specific one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that *the program will exit if it can't be initialized*. Just move the rest of the code inside the try.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    try {
      Config c = new Config();
      final NetworkReporter np = new NetworkReporter(c.getValues().serverIP, c.getValues().serverPort, (short)(c.getValues().checkInterval * c.getValues().checksPerReport));
      IdleChecker idleChecker = new IdleChecker(c.getValues().checkInterval, c.getValues().checksPerReport, c.getValues().idleSensitivity, new IdleChecker.reportFunction() {
        public void report() {
            np.report();
        }   
      }); 
      idleChecker.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error while parsing/reading file: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or even better, move the variable `c` into the `try` block as well.

Comment: @Alexis note that this is a bad practice. Try-catch blocks should be as small as possible. And Exceptions shouldn't be caught at all.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.exit(-1)
```

**Doesn't guarantee** that your program will come to a halt. If you have some sort of *shutdown hook*, or if you're in the middle of a stream operation, it can be prevented. Thus the compiler is throwing an error.

You might want to let the `Exception` escape the current layer.

```
Config c;

try {
    c = new Config();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error while parsing/reading file: " + e.getMessage());
    throw new YourCustomRuntimeException(e);
}

c.whatever();
```

Answer (score 0):

"and in fact - it will always be initialized (because the program will exit if it can't be initialized)."

How would the compiler know this? Further, if it will always be initialised, then why bother using a `try-catch` at all? There's a flaw in your logic.

You can move the rest of your code inside the `try`block. That would work.